# OCSP Stapling for Thawte certificates does not work

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ocsp

OCSP Stapling does not work for Thawte certificates on Nginx, what could be the problem?

Configured Nginx to work with OCSP Stapling.

```
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /ssl/ssl_trusted_certificate.crt;
```

The ssl_trusted_certificate.crt certificate includes the stitched root.crt and intermediate.crt.

The verification request indicates that OCSP Stapling is still off:

```
Openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxx:443 -tls1 -tlsextdebug -status
```

Result:

```
OCSP Response: No response sent
```

Who knows this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was not in the certificate and server settings. In order for OCSP Stapling to work, you need to go through a couple of pages of the site. On the first request, the server will request data from the certification center servers, and then go to OCSP.